# Android Room Database: How to embed multiple entities

Tags: database, kotlin, persistence, android-room

I am using room for my new project, but I am struggling with how to access one-to-one values cleanly
I have entities for addresses, owners and sites, both owners and sites have an associated address, and each site has an owner
is it possible to access these cleanly eg `site.owner.address.l1`?

I have looked into `@Relation` though it returns a list which is less than ideal

Entities

```
@Entity(tableName="addresses")
data class Address(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name="address_id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name="address_l1")
    val l1: String
)

@Entity(tablename="owners")
data class Owner(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name="owner_id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name="owner_name")
    val name: String
)

@Entity(tableName="sites")
data class Site(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name="site_id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name="site_addressid")
    val addressid: Int

    @ColumnInfo(name="site_ownerid")
    val ownerid: Int
)
```

Dao's

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM sites")
fun getSites(): List<Site>

@Query("SELECT * FROM owners")
fun getOwners(): List<Owner>

@Query("SELECT * FROM addresses")
fun getAddresses(): List<Address>

@Query("SELECT * FROM sites JOIN address ON sites.site_addressid = address.address_id JOIN owners ON sites.site_ownerid = owners.owner_id JOIN address ON owners.owner_addressid = address.address_id WHERE sites.site_id = :siteid")
fun getSiteByIdWithDetails(siteid): Site
```

---

I can only see the method of multiple POJO's to make this work such as
*not valid but roughly correct*

```
data class OwnerAddress(
    @Embedded
    val owner: Owner,

    @Embedded
    val address: Address
)

data class SiteAddress(
    @Embedded
    val site: Site,

    @Embedded
    val owner: OwnerAddress,

    @Embedded
    val address: Address
}
```

and using it via

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM sites JOIN address ON sites.site_addressid = address.address_id JOIN owners ON sites.site_ownerid = owners.owner_id JOIN address ON owners.owner_addressid = address.address_id WHERE sites.site_id = :siteid")
fun getSiteByIdWithDetails(siteid): SiteAddress
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Did you solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried building relationships between your Entities? [Android Documentation for Relationships](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships)

```
@Entity(tableName="addresses")
data class Address(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name="address_id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name="address_l1")
    val l1: String
)

@Entity(tablename="owners")
data class Owner(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name="owner_id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name="owner_name")
    val name: String

    @ColumnInfo(name="owner_adress")
    @Entity val adress: Address
)

@Entity(tableName="sites")
data class Site(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name="site_id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name="site_owner")
    @Embedded val owner: Owner

    @ColumnInfo(name="site_address")
    @Embedded val address: Address
)
```

So now your Site has an Address, and an Owner(which has its address). Both your `sites` table and `owners` table will contain Address columns as well.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Providing links is fine but its a good practice to provide additional explanations on how it answer's the initial question

Comment: Added the corresponding code snippet, hope it clarifies my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a TypeConverter and the [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library for your scope.

Define your data classes as

```
@Entity(tableName="addresses")
data class Address(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name="address_id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name="address_l1")
    val l1: String
)

@Entity(tablename="owners")
data class Owner(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name="owner_id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name="owner_name")
    val name: String
)

@Entity(tableName="sites")
data class Site(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name="site_id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name="site_address")
    val address: Address,

    @ColumnInfo(name="site_owner")
    val owner: Owner
)
```

Then create a `DatabaseConverter` class

```
class DatabaseConverter 
{
    @TypeConverter
    fun ownerFromJson(jsonString: String) : Owner {
        val ownerType = object : TypeToken<Owner>() { }.type
        return Gson().fromJson(jsonString, ownerType)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun jsonFromOwner(owner: Owner) : String = Gson().toJson(owner)

    @TypeConverter
    fun addressFromJson(jsonString: String) : Address {
        val addressType = object : TypeToken<Address>() { }.type
        return Gson().fromJson(jsonString, addressType)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun jsonFromAddress(address: Address) : String = Gson().toJson(address)
}
```

And then attach it to your `RoomDatabase` instance class

```
@Database(entities = [ ... ], version = ...)
@TypeConverters(DatabaseConverter::class)
abstract class YourDatabaseClass: RoomDatabase() {
    ...
}
```

You should now be able to access your sub-entities instances with

```
site.site_address.id 
site.site_owner.id
```